# Cannot determine element in firefox to change css

Tags: html, css

I have a multi-level drop down menu at http://www.theseymourgroup-comm.net/new/. If you hover over Properties, you will see the first drop down menu come down that includes Commercial and Development. But when you hover over Commercial, you will see that the next level with Active and Sold goes way out to the right. I right clicked that panel and chose inspect element but could not determine what I needed to change in the css to make it move over to hug the first drop down menu. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And what is the current CSS? Few people are going to go through and find the CSS on their own to help you. How about the HTML?

Comment: That is my problem...I cannot determine which element to find it in css

Comment: I've got to be misunderstanding -- you can't read through the HTML to find the element?

Answer (score 0):

The element with the "Active" and "Sold" entries is absolutely positioned, but it doesn't have settings for `top` or `left / right`.

If you add this rule

```
.nav li ul ul {
  left: 150px;
}
```

you'll come closer to what you want. (I leave the finetuning of that value to yourself...)

Answer (score 0):

I think javascript have some problems. `Menu Dropdown` use css only.

This is [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/easywebsitesmaker/wnu4uh5n). It's very simple for newbie